# Convert base64 image to in memory file in Python

Tags: python, io

I have a json file that contains resumes in base64 image where I need to decode them before being able read the contents of the file. Currently my process is to 1) decode 2) save as a physical file 3) reread them into python to get the content.

I would like to avoid step 2 and create the file in memory. I have successfully done this for PDFs and DOCx files, but I cannot get it to work for doc files. Since docx2txt does not read Doc files, I convert them to docx by using OS to open and save as.  I can do this with physical files, but cant get it to work using BytesIO. Below is my code, with my error. Any idea what I am doing wrong or a better way of doing this?

```
#Works for PDFs
resume= (df.iloc[76]['Candidate_Resume_Attachment_Base64_Image'])
resume_bytes = resume.encode('ascii')
decoded = base64.decodebytes(resume_bytes)
result = BytesIO()
result.write(decoded)
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(result)
page_count = pdfReader.numPages
pdf_total=[]
for i in range(page_count):
    page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    original=(page.extractText())
    pdf_total.append(original)
print(pdf_total)

#Works for DOCX files too
resume = (df.iloc[180]['Candidate_Resume_Attachment_Base64_Image'])
resume_bytes = resume.encode('ascii')
decoded = base64.decodebytes(resume_bytes)
result = BytesIO()
result.write(decoded)
original = docx2txt.process(result)
print(original)

#Cant get it to work for DOC files
message=((df.iloc[361]['Candidate_Resume_Attachment_Base64_Image']))
resume_bytes = message.encode('ascii')
decoded = base64.decodebytes(resume_bytes)
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = False
result = BytesIO()
result.write(decoded)
doc = word.Documents.Open(result)
doc = word.ActiveDocument
doc.DisplayAlerts = False
doc.Activate ()
doc.Repaginate()
num_of_sheets = doc.ComputeStatistics(2)

#traceback error
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-271-aefb69ec27f4>", line 9, in <module>
    doc = word.Documents.Open(result)

  File "C:\Users\Rizwan\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x7\Documents.py", line 93, in Open
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(19, LCID, 1, (13, 0), ((16396, 1), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17)),FileName

com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 16)
```

Comment: *.doc is an old binary format. I don't think docx2txt supports it. You will need to find another word library.

Comment: Correct, as mentioned above, I am not using docx2txt to open the doc files. I am using OS to open the doc files and save as docx.